# Firebase advanced queries

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know it's a high discussed topic, but for me it's still not clear which is the best approach to create advanced queries in Firebase.

Currently I'm using Angular 2 in the frontend and Firebase + NodeJS (Admin SDK) in the backend on an App engine.

Frontend: Auth / Simple queries / writing non sensitive data

NodeJS: Writing high sensitive data / validation

Works perfectly fine!

But now I want to create advanced queries and here's where I struggle:

- Firebase's built in query's are not powerful enough
- Client side would be too bad for performance reasons.
- Same for server side. I would need to transfer all the unqueried data anyways to my server.

So is there any good approach to avoid transfer unqueried data? Maybe since I'm using the gcloud anyways for the admin sdk?

I really miss something like custom endpoints.

THX in advance!

Comment: Way to vague a question. Your definition of 'advanced query' and mine could be very different. Please provide a specific example, show some code and your Firebase structure. Also, check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Update your question and we'l try to help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google's answer to 'why can't you do advanced queries?' is simply "Restructure your data, so you don't need to do advanced queries"

This may seem like a cheap crop-out, but the idea is since firebase is supposedly real-time, it needs to query data as fast as possible, and there might not be enough 'time'/'resources' to do serve advanced queries. This makes sense from google's point-of-view because they can't simply dedicate more server resources just for you to consume. In google's mind its simple, "We provide you all the data when you need it, it's your job to make it consistent, and do whatever you want with it"

Because of this, your Node backend has to act like a server proxy, where it fetches the actual data from firebase, and do the advanced queries on that data, and return the queried data back to the client. Or, you can go server-less and directly do this on the client, but this, as you mentioned might not always be secure for that high sensitive data.

Basically, you can't avoid unqueried data, but can keep that unqueried data minimal. This can be achieved by restructuring your data.

The advice google gives you is,

> Structure your data according to your views - Firebase, Google

What this means is that, say if had a view that shows information about an invoice. Traditionally, if you're coming from SQL, you'd design something like this

```
 + invoice
   + i01
     + date: xxx
     + customer: xxx
 + invoice_items 
   + ii01
     + invoice: i01
     + product: p
     + qty: 1
...
```

What google wants you to do is

```
 + invoice
   + i01
     + date: xxx
     + customer: xxx
     + items: [
        {
          + product: p
          + qty: 1
        }]
...
```

this way, you don't 'need' to do an advanced query, because all the data you'll ever need for your view is already there.

This may seem like a step back, because if you think about it, this only leads the database state into a inconsistent state, sooner or later, and you're correct, it does sometimes does that. But Firebase does provide measures to counter that, like [multipath updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: THX. Very good answer, made me rethinking my db structure! I think I'll write all queries server side. And save them after the first call in a different node. (something like caching)

Comment: You explained very well the reasons behind the trade-offs. Very helpful answer.